# httplib.ResponseNotReady When access token is being refreshed;

Tags: python, python-2.7, web2py, httplib, google-calendar-api

I'm tasked with implementing google calendar on a client's web site - they want to be able to select available calendars from their signed in google account, view/add/edit/delete events.

I've followed the example https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/web-app (I use web2py framework though, but it's quite similar)

First - everything works fine all the time on my local machine;
Secondly - everything works fine for one hour (rarely a bit more), then breaks, then somewhat starts working again on the production server;

I am storing the credentials to a database (After I get this over with (hopefully), I'll work on securing/encrypting the data) My code goes like this:

```
# just to show what "user.auth_user.google_credentials" is, from another function, where I do the oauth2callback stuff, and store it to the database
def oauth2callback():
    ...
    auth_code = request.vars['code']
    credentials = auth_flow.step2_exchange(auth_code)
    db(db.auth_user.id == auth.user_id).update(google_credentials=credentials.to_json())
    redirect(URL(..))

# where it starts to fall apart
credentials = client.OAuth2Credentials.from_json(user.auth_user.google_credentials)
http_auth = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())  # fails here if access_token_expired

calendar_service = discovery.build('calendar', 'v3', http=http_auth, cache_discovery=False)
all_calendars = calendar_service.calendarList().list().execute()

user_info_service = discovery.build('oauth2', 'v2', http=http_auth, cache_discovery=False)
user_info = user_info_service.userinfo().get().execute()
```

I then return some data to a view, where I generate a select box where options are the calendars, and on select box change event, I call a different function I have, to get events of selected calendar;

```
def get_google_calendar_events():
    user = db(db.auth_user.id == auth.user_id).select().first() # retrieve logged in user from db
    credentials = client.OAuth2Credentials.from_json(user.auth_user.google_credentials)
    http_auth = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http()) # also fails here if access token expired
    calendar_id = request.vars.calendar_id  # e.x. "primary"
    calendar_service = discovery.build('calendar', 'v3', http=http_auth, cache_discovery=False)
    events = calendar_service.events().list(calendarId=calendar_id, ...).execute()  # I have more options here, but I doubt it's relevant, just min/max dates etc;
    # Then I do some parsing, and just return the events where I apply styles, javascript, etc.
```

I get the error at:
httplib.py method "getresponse" Line ~1025;

```
if self.__state != _CS_REQ_SENT or self.__response:
    raise ResponseNotReady()
```

I've figured out that this is where it fails:

```
if self.__state != _CS_REQ_SENT
# in my case, all failed cases were:
"Idle" != "Request-sent"
# self.__response was (probably?) correctly None
```

I have no idea where to go from debugging "Idle" != "Request-sent", maybe someone knows?

As I've said, this works on my local machine all the time, perfectly;
Interestingly, if I ssh tunnel the server to localhost, it also works perfectly.
After one hour, it starts raising these exceptions, but after a few minutes it can sort of start to work ~Okayish again, but with (seems random amount) of errors;

I have zero experience with curl, or writing my own requests, but at this point I'm thinking of giving it a shot - is it possible to refresh an access_token with curl?

Rewriting everything with Javascript is not an option;

Sorry for the wall of text here, I'm pulling my hair out for two days now;
Any insight much appreciated !

P.S. I've showed that I have multiple "discovery.build" methods in one action - I've tried deleting "user_info_service" - to no avail, it's not the case, I might be wrong about something though, so that's why I left it in the snippet

Comment: After a lot of time and much searching I found that sometimes there are attempts to open a socket connection to address 2a00:1450:400f:808::200a with port 443 - and this is where I get timeouts, most likely because of incorrect ipv6 config in the production server; This is *probably* the case.

Answer (score 0):

Solution not found, Ipv6 is not the problem, sometimes just socket connection fails with "Errno 0: Error"

The socket is being "wrapped?" by SSLSocket, and sometimes fail on the handshake, I wrapped it in a silly try/except block ~ line 140ish ssl.py python 2.7.3:

```
try:
   self.do_handshake()
except Exception, e:
   print 'handshake err: {0}\n'.format(e)
```

And I get: "handshake err: [Errno 0] Error"
I'm clueless on what to actually do here, since the do_handshake is compiled C ?